# how to organize answers from dropdown options based on submitted input

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

The assumption is that I have an input field for quiz answers

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
   <span class="input-group-text">A</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" name="data[jawaban][]" placeholder="jawaban A">
   </div>
 </div>
```

and next I want to organize the current quiz answers based on the dropdown

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text">*</span>
     <select class="form-select" name="data[is_correct][]" id="correctAnswerSelect">
         <option selected>Pilih Jawaban</option>
         <option value="A">A</option>
         <option value="B">B</option>
         <option value="C">C</option>
         <option value="D">D</option>
         <option value="E">E</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

the output I get now is like this, in controllers laravel

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $optionResults = [];
    
        try {
            $question = Soal::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'kelas_id' => $request->input('kelas_id'),
                'pelajaran_id' => $request->input('pelajaran_id'),
                'isi_soal' => $request->input('data.isi_soal')[0]
            ]);
            
            $jawaban = $request->input('data.jawaban');
            $is_correct_options = $request->input('data.is_correct');
            foreach ($jawaban as $key => $isi_jawaban) {
                $optionResult = [
                    'Jawaban' => $isi_jawaban,
                    'Is_correct' => $is_correct_options,
                ];
            
                $optionResults[] = $optionResult;
            }
            
    
            DB::commit();
    
            return response()->json($optionResults, 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
        
            return response('Error: ' . $e->getMessage(), 500);
        }
    }
}
```

{"Jawaban":"no","Is_correct":["C"]}]

```
and my expected output is like this

> [{"Jawaban":"eat","Is_correct":["0"]},{"Jawaban":"sleep","Is_correct":["0"]},{"Jawaban":"work","Is_correct":["1"]},{"Jawaban":"tired","Is_correct":["0"]},{"Jawaban":"no","Is_correct":["0"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a check to see if the current answer corresponds to the selected correct option in the dropdown. If it does, it assigns '1' to 'Is_correct,' indicating the right answer. Otherwise, it sets '0' to 'Is_correct.' This should give you the output you want.

```
// Loop through and assign the correct index
foreach ($key => $isi_jawaban in $jawaban) {
    $optionResult = [
        'Jawaban' => $isi_jawaban,
        'Is_correct' => ($key == $is_correct_options[0]) ? '1' : '0', 
    ];

    $optionResults[] = $optionResult;
}
```